# Keytool error: Failed to establish chain from reply

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, x509certificate, keytool

I'm having an error in importing the trial SSL certificate from CA. Below is my steps in creating the keystore. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you in advance!

1.First, I created a keystore to be put in the server.

```
keytool -keystore server_keystore.jks -genkey -alias server -keyalg rsa -keysize 2048
```

2.Created a CSR.

```
keytool -keystore server_keystore.jks -certreq -alias server -keyalg rsa -file server.csr
```

- Sent the CSR to CA (Thawte) and replied with three trial certificate namely, CA root, CA intermediate and trial SSL. Saved it to a text file with file extension .cer. (trial_ca_ssl.cer, trial_ca_root.cer, trial_ca_intermediate.cer)

3.Tried to import the trial_ca_ssl.cer in server_keystore.jks but I received an error.

```
keytool -import -keystore server_keystore.jks -file trial_ca_ssl.cer -alias server
```

Error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply
```

Comment: Try to import first the CA root, then the CA intermediate and then, the last one, the trial SSL. I think it should work.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: Possible answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/23611688/148690

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23611688.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your `trial_ca_ssl.cer` text on top of top `server.cer`. This will make a hierarchy of two certificate like this. Then you should import it.

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIIEvabM2CgLZcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwMzETMBEGA1UE
>   AxMKV2FsdGVyIENBMTEPMA0GA1UEChMGV2FsdGVyMQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTAeFw0w
>   MzA5MjkwOTI2MzRaFw0wNDA5MjgwOTM2MzRaMDMxEzARBgNVBAMTCldhbHRlciBD
>   QTExDzANBgNVBAoTBldhbHRlcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0UwggEgMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
>   AQUAA4IBDQAwggEIAoIBAQC3hXksEud68WwPWWHLJQQkTCuX/K32KHPPn/uPUzab
>   Cpc/FnaTmF9yEHmpFdAUr0v5ZPnxVQpcuwrDZc4YfaTLfyUHicQbkftsPAj/2hE4
>   UukS2j+nQQcJEnIY0vSZOAOLU3j4bf/RlS6Jl7TPFFfWTxuQF8AruQ+YhaE52JFi
>   SapGGXKQJxhsvKT91rLaWSFWNMTTLSDPaBXYEYFuFhLNclDJWf4whfxHSHHkARB/
>   3Z0XlT4sFj0fmqEQ6yQb6/WqMFK+1XAIBXZO2MXe26IigWkXw1GfkIx1+fbUPrzu
>   8EI2jb0TWl21j1+Mvh3APZtVj5FJNuZN9bgdbrq88hLXAgERo2QwYjAPBgNVHRMB
>   Af8EBTADAQH/MA8GA1UdDwEB/wQFAwMHBgAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFNhHOtAwo8MOE/nI
>   zzg9KFxCYs8YMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFNhHOtAwo8MOE/nIzzg9KFxCYs8YMA0GCSqG
>   Sib3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBHpvicbuJTACtpdwe6cF1nQ57FHnnYr+aAe+ZpH43R6R9d
>   eMps02nFAMSs5o8sbPokrpwAtk2yYwCohEFDkZ5JPzIBkgNlNnVHNNRHQTRJ6v6Q
>   F2MWUEPc1u5kxSjXEVMmZerG9oknMwpYFmkOnKF46vP3Njt/ExOeRAvCEQq2b8pz
>   2QGg8/IK6Omfi7IwxtVYUpgvhdcWekbFIlxkXZiEdlHNBIV1GzzPK1VEzg5kugD/
>   h6jeykrsKASx+55AkkBPt2kI+ZikVtp3SVhfZQMGY86c5QMQGlPWYNsr4ociyhfX
>   I52Qby+/HNG1ijpx66Z30lUMmXTtWtL4Cu8s7UvC
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIICxzCCAa+gAwIBAgIIBfqGjbQu14swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwMzETMBEGA1UE
>   AxMKV2FsdGVyIENBMTEPMA0GA1UEChMGV2FsdGVyMQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTAeFw0w
>   MzA5MjkwOTMzMDFaFw0wNDAxMDcwOTQzMDFaMDQxETAPBgNVBAMTCER1ZGUgQ0Ex
>   MRIwEAYDVQQKEwlEdWRlIEluYy4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlNFMIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
>   AQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQCM1hR/DYPXfKDa3oVJbppV4OcYtn2XP9W5Kc1d0+U4qLOm
>   JsqIFHDWR07o1QFiPhc9z0UGtwYeE3CpQ8fG8zeur5e286PYptZIST77B9vOdQdl
>   PA+dFKFIaEwdzcS7H3Lf38WTE4D1OnyRX5jsiUe+YIQRtjv/Bmem+kSR84G9TwIB
>   EaNkMGIwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAPBgNVHQ8BAf8EBQMDBwYAMB0GA1UdDgQW
>   BBTDrXZGYXS9GyIUBOZrglhwNjjcnTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTYRzrQMKPDDhP5yM84
>   PshcQmLPGDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAdmTP1qVUcAKOf+/zvb2lcLKvFwKT
>   6KqDlO5NofjqCIfNgCjO2mO176cslnFIbEZQqgGIUnJ3AwfHKHj+U3kM3n5T29kF
>   xiLKxIDfjsY6qC03KHeGAgxI92XZyPsO1is6Y6qUnAmiwhIp5HS6E0+xIP1shmtJ
>   ZvqU8bueKUWSjx3JDzq+UNLX5pFkK0P0R90TCUEkBx1FNWqoWwb8zfAuO5zcNTEj
>   5E9esLjwxJQnIVPiA2l3FfZN9yomK+q7kTZJkX2kMx7G850lPR8CneXZT6bIOfck
>   Dw3PqQiroMNx2+gzC/f/wTXsF92aujyG+IZx1FIcNg/MoHXBWG7T8YrjnQ==
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

For details read the User Guide of [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/userguide.html).

Answer (score -2):

one possibility is that you use the default openssl tool in Mac, but you copy \openssl\apps\ca-cert.srl from a newer version openssl.

Comment: He is using the Java keytool, not OpenSSL. Read the question.